# Rhombus and circles angle problem

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a rhombus.
The circle $(C_1)$ of center $B$ passing through $C$ and the circle $(C_2)$ of center $C$ passing through $B$.
$E$ is one of the two points of $(C_1) \cap (C_2)$.
The line $(ED)$ meets $(C_1)$ again in $F$.
It is asked to find the measure of angle $\angle AFB$.

I tried a lot of angle chasing but in vain.

I even took a square instead just to find out a means to a solution but failed to get the value.

From geogebra, the measure would be $60^{\circ}$.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A fast approach using Euclidean geometry**

[image]

1. Since $\mathcal C_1$ and $\mathcal C_2$ have the same radius,
   $\triangle BEC$ is equilateral.
2. $BE$ subtends on $\mathcal C_2$ the angle $\angle BDE$, which therefore has measure $30^\circ$, and \begin{eqnarray}\angle ADE &=& \frac12 \angle ADC + 30^\circ\\ &=& \frac12 \angle ABC + 30^\circ.\end{eqnarray}
3. On the other hand, $AE$ subtends on $\mathcal C_1$ the angle $\angle AFE$, by which we have \begin{eqnarray}180^\circ- \angle AFE &=& \frac12 \angle EBA=\\ &=& \frac12 \left(\angle ABC + 60^\circ\right).\end{eqnarray}
4. By 2. and 3. $\triangle AFD$ is isosceles, with $AD \cong AF$ and the thesis follows from the fact that $AB \cong AD \cong BF$.

**EDIT** (thanks to [bjorn93](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36iTB.png) for his useful comment.)
The situation when $ED<EF$ is shown below. However, as you can notice, the relationships found above do not change.

[image]

Comment: @ahmed Note that there's actually two cases depending on the relative position of D, E, and F. In the second case, $\angle ADE= \frac 12\angle ABC-30^{\circ}$.

Comment: @bjorn93 edited; check it out. I think the relationship between $\angle ADE$ and $\angle ABC$ does *not* change.

Comment: well, there's actually more than 2 cases for the position of the points. For example, D and E can be in the same half-plane with respect to BC and $\angle BDE$ can be $150^{\circ}$. What I meant is that they give you 2 cases for the angles: $\angle ADE=\frac 12\angle ABC\pm 30^{\circ}$.

Comment: @bjorn93 ah ok! Got it. Now I turned off my PC, but as soon as possible I'll show one of the cases you mention. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. In any case, we get the same answer and the solution is similar to yours with slight adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

It should be clear that $\triangle BEC$ is equilateral. Denote $\angle BFD=\alpha$ and $\angle AFD=\beta$. We need to find $\alpha+\beta$. You can show that $\angle ADF=60^{\circ}-\alpha$ through some angle chasing. Sine law for $\triangle ADF$ gives you
$$\frac{AD}{AF}=\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin(60^{\circ}-\alpha)} $$
and the sine law for $\triangle ABF$ gives you
$$\frac{AB}{AF}=\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin(2(\alpha+\beta))}=\frac{1}{2\cos(\alpha+\beta)} $$
Since $AB=AD$,
$$\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin(60^{\circ}-\alpha)}=\frac{1}{2\cos(\alpha+\beta)} $$
Can you prove that the last equality implies $\beta=30^{\circ}$ or $\alpha+\beta=60^{\circ}$ and that $\beta=30^{\circ}$ is a contradiction?